# How to make hjkl with shift more flexible?

Tags: key-bindings

Currently I have the following maps:

```
nmap J 5j
nmap K 5k
nmap L 5l
nmap H 5h
```

This works great if I hit Shift j, it moves down for quick cursor movement. However if I let go of shift while holding j to go back to regular movement speed the cursor stops.

The same is true for if I am moving slowly by holding j then hit shift to accelerate. It just stops. Any work around for this?

*I am using git bash in windows.*

As much as holding down keys is an anti pattern, some mornings I am not up to thinking harder to use better movements.

Comment: Using J,K,L,H for h,k,j,l is usually discouraged. You can use other options to scroll the screen. Have you tried options like `Ctrl-E`?

Comment: Matter of opinion, I am used to this and this makes sense to me.

Comment: Matter of fact, actually. `hjkl` are for moving the cursor while `<C-u>`, `<C-d>` and friends are for scrolling.

Comment: My mistake I meant cursor movement, not scrolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of remapping, you should consider the other options for moving the cursor around, i.e.

```
C-D        Move the cursor Down one page (controlled by the 'scroll' option)
C-U        Move the cursor Up one page (controlled by the 'scroll' option)
M          Move the cursor to the Middle line of the window
H          Move the cursor to the Highest line of the window
L          Move the cursor to the Lowest line of the window
```

Also, considering you know where you want to go (which is not the case all the time), take advantage of the `/`, `?`, `G`, `%` commands:

```
/pattern   Search for the next pattern    
?pattern   Search for the previous pattern   
NG         Go to line N   (Ngg does the same)
N%         Go to the Nth percentage of the file.
```

If you are in a structured language, note the following commands that moves the cursor to the start/end of the following/previous function: `]m`, `]M`, `[m`, `[M`.

Doing some C/C++/... ? `[#`, `]#` jumps to conditional macros (`#if`, `#else`, ...)

Moving across `/* */` comments? `[*`, `]*`, `[/`, `]/` are your friends.

You can also jump to the next/previous `{}()` with `[{`,`[(`, `]}`, `])`.

Soo, my point here is that you already have a lot of ways to move around in Vim (there's more than the little list I made). So I would suggest learning those ways before trying to remap core commands as `j` or `k`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing how I use vim not the problem I was having with vim. (Sounds sarcastic but is serious)

Comment: My answer was kind of non-answering your question so no offence taken ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would find it enormously frustrating to have the normal functions of `H`, `J` and `L` supplanted; those are "top of screen", "join line", and "bottom of screen" respectively.

I consider that re-mapping `J` is downright dangerous, because if the mapping fails (or you log into a new machine without your `.vimrc`), you wind up mangling the file.

As for why the auto-repeat stops when you press or release the shift key, that's a feature of the terminal (emulator), not of vi or vim.