# Possible to increase cursor move speed when holding down (h/j/k/l)?

Tags: neovim, cursor-movement

Is it possible to increase cursor move speed when holding down (h/j/k/l) ? If so, how?

Comment: unless you're using gvim or other gui, this has more to do with your terminal than vim

Comment: I've deleted a few comments (including my own) that weren't really using comments as intended—comments are for clarification and improvement. Discussions on better ways to move can happen in [chat] if folks want. Frame-challenge answers are also welcome, but should be polite.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9063/10604, https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/o26h8/ask_rvim_can_you_change_the_speed_of_cursor/,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to do from within vim or gvim. That is what operating system does for all keypresses (I doubt you can separately increase it only for specific keypresses)

For windows it is:
[image]

For OSX or linux there should be similar settings.

I would suggest to use more navigation facilities vim has:

1. `/funcname<CR>nnn` search if you know specific function
2. `}` goto next paragraph
3. `C-f` scroll page down
4. `C-d` scroll half a page down
5. `tag *func*name<tab>` if you have tags
6. `H`, `M`, `L` to go to top, middle and bottom of the screen
7. plugin easymotion
8. ... many more

Answer (score 2):

As a bit of a frame-challenge, consider learning some more `:help motion` (the full list is long; take it slow!).

Some particular useful ones:

- search `/` and `?`, along with shortcuts `*`/`gd`/etc.
- scrolling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and any of `d`/`u`/`b`/`f`
- moving in a line `f`/`F`/`t`/`T`
- various text-object motions `)`/`}`/etc.
- marks/tags/etc.

As a bonus, these motions combine orthogonally with operators, so you get a 2-for-1: faster movement and faster editing when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If cursor movement one-place-at-a-time takes too long, then perhaps it's worth learning some other options.

Firstly, try prefacing with a number, to move that many places; eg. `24h` will move 24 places to the left.

Secondly, how about moving by words (`b`/`w`)?

Thirdly, how about jumping directly to a specific column? e.g. `17|` will move to column 17 (which because numbering starts at 1, is 16 places away from the left edge, and matches the 2nd tab-stop if you have `:set ts=8`).